# Vuejs and css not working on firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, vue.js

I have a site where I click on a item and it shows the result in side. i.e grid is full width at first, when a item is clicked it shows information by dividing the grid in 8/4. The items are in a loop. This works fine on chrome. But on firefox if I click some random item like 4th or 5th unusual behavior shows up. The result doesnot pops up at the side. But if I click the first item, it works well.

Comment: Do you have any code or a jsfiddle? :)

Comment: The code is large and cannot be shared here.